# Access Laravel stored files from android app (ionic).

Tags: json, laravel, ionic-framework, storage

I'm working on an android app with Ionic 3 connected with Laravel to control my data through an api, and i'm trying to display a bunch of images on my ionic app, the problem is i can't.

I was trying to access laravel's storage folder but i can't, i don't know if it's possible to convert a blob image to json ...

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

By default, laravel's storage folder can't be seen to the public web.

When you access your laravel app, you are actually accessing the 'public' folder of the root structure. Therefore, only the application has access to the storage folder.

Run the following in your command line in root folder

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This will create a symbolic link from public/storage to app/storage/public.

Now, you'll have to put your images inside the app/storage/public folder, and access them trough http://[yoursitehere].com/storage/image1.png

Comment: Tried it, but my ionic app return an error, " http://[link]/storage/images/[imgname]" 404 (not found) ...

Comment: I am serving laravel on a shared host, so i can access its api from the ionic app

Comment: NP! Sorry I didn't see your comments in time, but I'm glad you worked it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to link your storage directory to your public folder so it's accessible.

Link the storage folder:

`php artisan storage:link`

Get the image URL:

`echo asset('storage/image.jpg');`

Check the documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#configuration

Comment: Oups, i didn't make myself clear, my bad, i actually meant i was trying to access laravel's storage from the ionic app ..., i can display the images just fine on laravel.

Comment: You are trying to access it through `ajax` or?

Comment: I'm using Laravel's api to get data from mysql database, and convert it to json object, and i recieve the json object on my ionic app and i display it, but i'm having trouble displaying images, if i use the `store()` function it stores the path and i can't access it from the ionic app. there's no ajax in there

Comment: So what you are saying is that your ionic app is inside of Laravel aka inside of **public** folder?

Comment: No they're separated, but i'm deploying laravel on a shared host `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0` so i can access its api from the ionic app that i deploy on my android device